# Can a storyboard handle orientation changes automatically?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I would like to design my iPhone App so that, e.g., my buttons are centered, or my inputs are set to the full viewport width and so on. Is this possible using only the storyboard, or do I have to create every view element in the controller and then alter it on orientation change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with "AutoLayout",

I would recommend this tutorial for a better understanding:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 5, Auto-layout is enabled by default.  You also may want to try adding the recommended constraints from the Editor menu.